# Как вызвать [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:(NSRange)] на Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c

Взял за основу создания календаря чужую библиотеку, она на Objective-C. Приложение пишу на Swift.
Помогите пожалуйста с этим куском кода, не могу понять как на Swift это реализовать:

```
//cv — это CollectionView
[cv performBatchUpdates:^{ 
        if (components.month < 0) {
         //Отсюда не понял как это на Swift реализовать
        [cv deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:(NSRange){
                cv.numberOfSections - abs(components.month),
                abs(components.month)
            }]];   
        }

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      //Nothing 
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv.performBatchUpdates({
    guard components.month < 0 else {
        return
    }
    let start = cv.numberOfSections - abs(components.month)
    let end = abs(components.month)
    let set = IndexSet.init(integersIn: start...end)
    cv.deleteSections(set)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь